# AngularJS Ошибка в работе функции

Tags: angularjs

Передаю в функцию id для выборки:

```
$scope.record = function(id) {
                $http.post("http://site.com/dev/record/", {id: id })
                  .then(function success(data) {
        console.log(data);
        $scope.SpisokVoprosov = data;
    }, function error(err) {
        console.log('Что-то пошло не так')
    });
```

};
В ответе `http://site.com/dev/record/` должно возвращаться:

```
[{"filename":"audio.mp3","type":"audio"}]
```

В итоге в консоли возвращается ошибка:

Что по Вашему вызывает ошибку?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

методы `success` и `error` стали устаревшими в одной из версий, и теперь, похоже, их все-таки удалили.

Вместо них, нужно использовать метод `then`

```
$scope.record = function(id) {
    $http.post("http://site.com/dev/record/", {id: id })
        .then(function success(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.SpisokVoprosov = data;
        }, function error(err) {
            console.log('Что-то пошло не так')
        });
};
```

Comment: Вы правы. Возник вопрос, почему в ответе от запроса возвращается null? [ скрин добавил в конце первоначального вопроса ]

Comment: @ВалерийОрлов, стоит задать отдельный вопрос.